# PersistenceException: unexpected error when rollbacking

Tags: java, memory, transactions

I am getting **PersistenceException** exceptiong because of the OOM error.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271)
        at java.lang.StringCoding.safeTrim(StringCoding.java:79)
        at java.lang.StringCoding.access$300(StringCoding.java:50)
        at java.lang.StringCoding$StringEncoder.encode(StringCoding.java:305)
        at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:344)
        at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:916)Heap dump file created [464734012 bytes in 39.704 secs]
```

I am trying to process a file having 80-100k lines. Each line will be stored as a row in the table. Every line has about 15-20 attributes. I want to understand how much memory will the DB Transaction (@Transactional) require to keep them in the entity manager and persist them at one go? 
Batching is not feasible due to our architecture design limitations.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are reading line by line, and getting this error, I had a issue similar. We had to process large files, and were not flushing the cache. I forget, I haven't used it in a long time, the ORM was hibernate, and we had to add either a call to flush or clear on the entity manager (you also want to make sure you're not doing everything in a single transaction, that will cause OOM too). I was surprised when I found out the inserts keep filling the cache until you get an OOM.

Comment: Yeah I'm doing all the inserts in one transaction because I want to rollback everything if something fails. My usecase it to make all inserts atomic. How can I accomplish the same with multiple transactions? Any idea?

Comment: I don't know a solid answer to that, but I suspect it will not be easy. The problem with a single transaction (even if you don't use something like hibernate, where the entities are kept in memory for each insert unless explicitly cleared) is you will create a large rollback segment, which can also cause problems on the app side as well as database side. I'm suspecting this may be solvable by not doing it in java. There maybe some ETL tools that can help, but I have not had to use any yet. If you have access to a good DBA, they may have some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the snippet of code you use to go through the test file and persist each line to a row in a database table?